# Unable to init uart with micropython & ttl to rs485

Tags: esp32, micropython, rs485

I'm using a board with the next GPIO as the image:
[image]
Also im ussing a TTL to RS-485 module at 5V with chipset MAX485.

| ESP32 | MAX485 |
| --- | --- |
| RX | DI |
| TX | RO |
| 15 | DE & RE |

When I add the line to init uart, the board doesn't reply more.

```
from machine import UART

print("hello")
uart = UART(1,baudrate=9600, bits=8, parity=None, stop=1, rx=3,tx=1)
print("bye")
```

As anyone know about what I'm doing bad?

many thanks

Answer (score -1):

Seems that board shares the tx+rx pins 1&3 with the usb debug, cause of that i lost my com with the esp32 and is the cause of "no response"